# Why is a function within an object constructor altering all objects previously created by that constructor?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

I have a function within an object constructor that is altering all objects created by that constructor. I'm not sure why. Could someone please take a look at my code and tell me what I'm missing?

A quick description of what is going on:

### Warning! It might be easier to just read through the code than try to make sense of my description

I have created two new Arrays. The first one called `foos`, which will be an array of `foo` objects each one containing an array of `bar` objects. The second is called `bars` which is an array of all `bar` objects that are available to be added to the `foos.foo.bars` arrays.

When a new `foo` object is created using the `foo` object constructor it is given two arguments(`aBars,bBars`). `aBars` is an array of all `bar` objects to be included in the `foo` object. `bBars` is an array of all included `bar` objects that are considered 'special' in some way. Within the constructor there is a function that runs through every object in the `bars` array and if it's name value matches that of a string in the `aBars` argument then it is added to `foo.bars` array. If it's name value matches a string in the `bBars` argument it then has it's property `bBar` set to true, otherwise it's set to false.

The issue I'm having is that on the second `foo` object constructor when a bar object has bBar set to true or false it also changes that value in that object in all other `foo.bars` objects.

I realize that this is probably hard to follow. Sorry about that, it's the end of the day.

---

### Found my own answer!

I just realized what the issue is. `foos[0].bars[4]` and `foos[1].bars[3]` are not separate objects, they are simply two different variables pointing to the same object. So when one is changed the change shows up on both. Wow, I can't believe I just spent so much time working on this when the answer was a basic fact about how javascript works that I learned back when I first started.

### Ok, the new question:

How can I change this code to create duplicates of the objects instead of just pointing at the originals? This is not something I've ever had to do before.

---

Thanks

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcarleton/6F92A/)

JS:

```
var foos = new Array();
var bars = new Array();

function foo(aBars,bBars) {
    var $this = this;
    this.aBars = aBars;
    this.bars = new Array();
    bars.forEach(function(e,i) {
        if ($this.aBars.lastIndexOf(e.barName) > -1) {
            $this.bars.push(e);
            if (bBars.lastIndexOf(e.barName) > -1) {
                $this.bars[$this.bars.length-1].bBar = true;
            } else {
                $this.bars[$this.bars.length-1].bBar = false;
            }
        }
    });
}
function bar(name) {
    this.barName = name;
}

bars.push(new bar('l'));
bars.push(new bar('m'));
bars.push(new bar('n'));
bars.push(new bar('o'));
bars.push(new bar('p'));

foos.push(new foo(['l','m','n','o','p'],['n','p']));
foos.push(new foo(['l','n','o'],['n','o']));

console.log(foos);
```

Comment: There's just an awful lot of things wrong with this code... But a couple of things: Don't use `new Array`, use `[]`. Always capitalize constructs. Convention matters. Whenever you're defining a function in a constructor, think _`prototype`_ and most of all: _read up on `this` and the call-context of the `forEach` callback_

Comment: Why shouldn't I use `new Array`? I've read, and was taught, that when defining an empty array `new Array` was better.

Yeah, I usually capitalize constructs, that was more of a typo in this due to trying to recreate the issue quickly in a jsfiddle.

How was I not 'thinking prototype'?

Comment: Where were you taught `new Array` is better? The array constructor [is slower](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375120/why-is-arr-faster-than-arr-new-array), it's badly overloaded (`new Array(10)` vs `new Array('10')`) and you were not thinking _prototype_ when you wrote `bars.foreach(function`, which isn't the same as `this.bars`, and which constructs a foreach callback for each instance you create. Best make that into a prototype method...

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I will start using `[]`. `bars.foreach()` is running the function for each object in the global variable `bars`. `this.bars` would target an empty array. The point of `bars.foreach` callbacks is to act as a filter only adding desired objects from the global variable to this new array. Am I missing your point here? I get your point about using a prototype method though, an overlook on my part for sure. Thanks for the help. I'm still relatively new to this and appreciate guidance wherever I can get it.

Comment: Well, having the behaviour of a constructor (or any function, for that matter) depend on a _global_ variable isn't what I'd call a great idea. Especially if that global variable has the same name as a property. If I were to see this code at work, I'd assume someone made a mistake and shout at him for using globals. I suggest you look into [closures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472577/javascript-how-to-make-this-code-work/16472719#16472719), so you can _"bind"_ the `bars` array to the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to achieve that would be to replace this line

```
$this.bars.push(e);
```

in your 'foo'-constructor with this one:

```
$this.bars.push(new bar(e.barName));
```

Cloning objects in javascript is only possible by copying their properties.