# Javascript rotation animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval, rotateanimation

I am stuck at a point.There are 10 straight lines(png image).What I want is after the first line rotates by 40 deg,then the second line should start its rotaion and then the third,fourth,fifth and so on!!!

code:

```
<div class="hair" onclick="rotate()">
    <img src="single.png" id="1" width="10" height="40">
    <img src="single.png" id="2" width="10" height="40">
    <img src="single.png" id="3" width="10" height="40">
    <img src="single.png" id="4" width="10" height="40">
    <img src="single.png" id="5" width="10" height="40">
    <img src="single.png" id="6" width="10" height="40">
    <img src="single.png" id="7" width="10" height="40">
    <img src="single.png" id="8" width="10" height="40">
    <img src="single.png" id="9" width="10" height="40">
    <img src="single.png" id="10" width="10" height="40">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function rotate(){
    for(var i=1;i<11;i++)
    {
        setInterval(function(){
            document.getElementById(i).style.WebkitTransitionDuration="1s";
            document.getElementById(i).style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(40deg)';
        },100)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of steps to solve your problem:

An ID in HTML cannot start with a number, so rename them to something like 'hair1', 'hair2', etc.

The main problem is that because of the setInterval, by the time the function runs, `i` will not be the `i` that you were expecting. This is because of variable scope. You can get around this with an anonymous function.

Combining both of the above gives this code:

```
<div class="hair" onclick="rotate()">
  <img src="single.png" id="hair1" width="10" height="40">
  <img src="single.png" id="hair2" width="10" height="40">
  <!-- etc -->
</div>

// NOTE: This is not the final code listing, see below for a final answer. 
for (var i = i; i < 11; i++) {
  (function(local_i) {
    setInterval(function () {
      // use local_i instead of i inside this function for the results you expect
      document.getElementById('hair' + local_i).style.WebkitTransitionDuration='1s';
      document.getElementById('hair' + local_i).style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(40deg)';
    }, 100);
  })(i);
}
```

I would also recommend putting the styles into a stylesheet, then apply them using a class:

```
.rotate
{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
}
```

Finally, to get the elements to rotate in a row rather than all together, you need to multiply the interval by the value of `i`. I think that you probably mean to use setTimeout rather than setInterval (setInterval will keep running over and over again).

```
function rotate(){
  for(var i=1;i<11;i++) {
    (function (local_i) {
      setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('hair' + local_i).classList.add('rotate');
      }, 100 * local_i);
    })(i);
  }
}
```

I've put together a [demo here](http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/latxg)

Comment: The demo doesn't work.All the `div`s rotate at once which is not what the OP wants

Comment: @harsha no they don't - the final code listing rotates each one in 100ms intervals. Check out the demo.

Comment: The reason why I said it doesn't work is because I saw the demo and it didn't work.

Comment: @jayeshjain in the demo I used index instead of local_i - sorry for the confusion - I'll update the demo code now! Classlist is like an array that contains all of the classes of an element that lets you easily add and remove classes. [More information on classlist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList)

Answer (score 2):

You're encountering the classic scope/closure/reference problem most people run into when using anonymous functions. I've [answered this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472577/javascript-how-to-make-this-code-work/16472719#16472719) a while back, and provided tons of info on what is actually happening (*Ignore the first paragraph of my answer, the rest of the answer is applicable, though*). Meanwhile, the answer to your problem is:

```
for(var i=1;i<11;i++)
{
    setInterval((function(myI)
    {
        return function()
        {
            document.getElementById(myI).style.WebkitTransitionDuration='1s';
            document.getElementById(myI).style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(40deg)';
        };
    }(i)),100);
}
```

Be aware that you're setting intervals: the callback will be called every 100ms as long as the browser window remains open. 
You're not storing the interval id anywhere, so I'd either use `setTimeout` or create a (preferably non-global) array of id's so you can do `clearInterval(intervalID[x]);` when you need to.

Comment: but the animation is not there,all the lines are rotating at the same time,which is something that i dont want.
This is what i want  
l l l l l l l l l l---initial position
/ l l l l l l l l l  ---1st animation  
/ / l l l l l l l l    ---2nd animation
/ / / l l l l l l l    ---3rd animation
and so on.

Comment: @jayeshjain: your animation is set to take +- 1 second, yet the interval is .1 of a second. Of course they'll all appear to rotate together. Furthermore. the 10th id will rotate ~10 times faster by the end of the first second... trust me: increase the interval (from 100 to 5000 or something to get a better view of things), and use an IIFE

Comment: I have already tried that,but the second line starts animating before the first line has ended its animation.
And whats iife

Comment: @jayeshjain: Read the linked answer to find out more about IIFE's (Immediatly Invoked Function Expression). Also: the intervals won't slow the foreach loop down one bit, you know... just make a callback sequence (queue) from within your first interval callback. setup a fiddle, and I'll take a look at it after lunch if needs must

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this on modern browsers, separating CSS and JS by using a class. This is my own example based on your requirements, using a common class `box` and modern tools and patterns:

Here's the HMTL, I'm using divs just because, but you can use images or any other element:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Keep the CSS separate, you just need to match the transition speed with the delay:

```
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 40px;
  background: grey;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s linear;
}

.box.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

And the JS:

```
function rotate() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
  [].forEach.call(elements, function(element, i) {
    setTimeout(function(){ element.classList.add('rotate'); },i*300);
  });
}

document.querySelector('.container')
        .addEventListener('click',rotate);
```

Here's little demo: http://jsbin.com/ofiral/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution, but something you can start with.

Define a css3 animation and assign it using javascript.

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
.hair {
    position:relative;
}
.hair div {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-animation-duration:         1s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:  infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

.

```
function rotate() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        (function (x) {
            setInterval(function () {
                document.getElementById("d" + x).style.WebkitAnimationName = "rotation";
            }, 200 * i);
        })(i);
    }
}

rotate();
```

adjust the `setInterval` dealy and `animation-duration` to get the desired result.

webkit demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NQJJp/5/