# Closures in recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, scope, closures

i have this two recursive functions in javascript.
first function returns digits of the input number in right to left order
second function returns them in left to right order.

```
function first(n){
    if(n > 0){
        m = Math.floor( n/10 );
        v = ( n - m * 10 ) + " " + first(m);
        return v;
    }
    return "";
}



function second(n){
    if(n > 0){
        m = Math.floor( n/10 );
        v = second(m) + " " + ( n - m * 10 );
        return v;
    }
    return "";
}
```

result of the first function is

```
7 6 1
```

result of the second function is

```
1 16 167
```

but I expected this

```
1 6 7
```

I tested similar code in PHP and JAVA and it works well. 
Presumably the problem is in Javascript's closures. But I cant figure how to fix it.

Comment: use "var" before your internal function variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly simple: You're using implied globals:

```
function second(n)
{
    if(n > 0)
    {
        m = Math.floor( n/10 );
        //m is changing here ------\\will use lowest value of m
        v = second(m) + " " + ( n - m * 10 );
        return v;
    }
    return "";
}
```

The fix is:

```
function second(n)
{
    if(n > 0)
    {
        //make declare it in the scope itself
        var m = Math.floor( n/10 );
        v = second(m) + " " + ( n - m * 10 );
        return v;
    }
    return "";
}
```

This still leaves you with the *evil* implied global `v`, too. If I were you, I'd declare `v` locally, too

```
function second(n)
{
    var m, v = '';
    n = +(n);//coerce to number
    if (n > 0)
    {
        m = Math.floor(n/10);
        v = second(m) + ' '+ (n-m*10);
    }
    return v;
}
```

This function works as expected.
The problem didn't really have to do with closures as such, but it was caused by [the way JS resolves expressions/names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472577/javascript-how-to-make-this-code-work/#16472719).
Couple that to how JS deals with recursive functions and you get the output you got, plain and simple.

*JS doesn't really have a recursive call-stack, yet. Last time I checked, recursive calls were effectively short-circuited (~= goto's). I remember reading something on the subject by Douglas Crockford, about it having something to do with the call-stack.

Though ES5's strict mode does introduce TCO, and it should make it by the end of 2013 (ES6 - Harmony). I've linked to a couple of sites [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/179863/performance-recursion-vs-iteration-in-javascript/181001#181001), if you care to read more on the matter*

Comment: @jangofett: You're welcome, though on SO, the way to thank somebody for helping you is voting/accepting the answer, not posting a thanks-comment