# how to select a TR on click it and remove selection when click another TR

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i have a table and i do some code here to change the table became editable and selectable...
my requirement is 
 1. when click a TR it should become blue color and again click another TR that will show the blue color and older one become white (menace non selectable)

i due some code it is workable but the reason is i already have some code for selecting the TD thats need for me i am struggle here i can't remove this td selection like the TR selection

```js
$(function() {
  $(".cat").dblclick(function() {
    var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
    $(this).addClass("cellEditing1")
    $(this).html("<input id='value' type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
  })


  $('tr').click(function() {
    $('tr').removeClass('selected1');
    $(this).addClass('selected1');

  });

  $(".cat").on("click", function() {
    $(this).removeClass('selected')
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
  $(".cat1").on("click", function() {
    $(this).removeClass('selected2')
    $(this).addClass('selected2');
  });

  $("#key").click(function() {

    var sl = parseInt($(".selected").css("padding-left"));
    sl = sl >= 20 ? "20" : "+=20";

    $(".selected").css({
      "padding-left": sl

    });
    var sq = parseInt($(".selected2").css("padding-left"));
    sq = sq >= 40 ? "40" : "+=20";

    $(".selected2").css({
      "padding-left": sq

    });
    $(".cat.selected").each(function() {
      var prevTd = $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').find('td:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')');
      console.log('Current td index: ' + $(this).index());
      console.log('Previous td content: ' + prevTd.text());

      prevTd.addClass("mainfunctionstyle");
      prevTd.find('input').addClass("mainfunctionstyle");



    });

    $(".cat1.selected2").each(function() {

      var paddingLeftpl = parseInt($(this).css("padding-left"));
      if (paddingLeftpl == 40) {
        $(".selected2").addClass("taskstyle");
        $(".selected2").find('input').addClass("taskstyle");
      }

    });
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.selected1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.selected2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.editableTable {
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.editableTable td {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 17px;
}
.editableTable .cellEditing1 input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.editableTable .cellEditing1 {
  padding: 0;
  height: 1px;
}
.mainfunctionstyle {
  color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.sunfunctionstyle {
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 8px;
}
.taskstyle {
  color: red;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="key">left</button>
<table class="editableTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="cat">rose11</td>
    <td class="cat">red12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cat">rose21</td>
    <td class="cat">red22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cat1">rose31</td>
    <td class="cat">red32</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cat2">rose41</td>
    <td class="cat">red42</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Why do the `.cat` and `.cat1` click functions remove and add the same class to `$(this)`?

Comment: that i due for removing the Td selection.

Comment: But it doesn't remove the TD selection, since both of them are just operating on `$(this)`. Did you mean to do `$('.cat').removeClass('selected')`?

Comment: yes ,you just see the out put now TR selection and non selection is ok but the TD selection remove is not working

Comment: The problem is that you're putting the classes on both the TR and the TD. When you click on a different row, you remove the class from the old TR, but you leave it on the old TD, so it's still blue.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is having this in your code:

```
$(".cat").on("click", function() {
    $(this).removeClass('selected')
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
  $(".cat1").on("click", function() {
    $(this).removeClass('selected2')
    $(this).addClass('selected2');
  });
```

You don't need to have a listener on the `td` elements since you have one on the tr elements doing the job. There's something called event propagation that means by default if you click an element, the parent of the clicked element will have its click element triggered as well, therefore you don't need to handle `td` clicks if you're looking for manipulating a `tr`.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".cat").dblclick(function() {
    var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
    $(this).addClass("cellEditing1")
    $(this).html("<input id='value' type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
  })


  $('tr').click(function() {
    $('tr').removeClass('selected1');
    $(this).addClass('selected1');

  });
  $("#key").click(function() {

    var sl = parseInt($(".selected").css("padding-left"));
    sl = sl >= 20 ? "20" : "+=20";

    $(".selected").css({
      "padding-left": sl

    });
    var sq = parseInt($(".selected2").css("padding-left"));
    sq = sq >= 40 ? "40" : "+=20";

    $(".selected2").css({
      "padding-left": sq

    });
    $(".cat.selected").each(function() {
      var prevTd = $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').find('td:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')');
      console.log('Current td index: ' + $(this).index());
      console.log('Previous td content: ' + prevTd.text());

      prevTd.addClass("mainfunctionstyle");
      prevTd.find('input').addClass("mainfunctionstyle");



    });

    $(".cat1.selected2").each(function() {

      var paddingLeftpl = parseInt($(this).css("padding-left"));
      if (paddingLeftpl == 40) {
        $(".selected2").addClass("taskstyle");
        $(".selected2").find('input').addClass("taskstyle");
      }

    });
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.selected1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.selected2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.editableTable {
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.editableTable td {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 17px;
}
.editableTable .cellEditing1 input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.editableTable .cellEditing1 {
  padding: 0;
  height: 1px;
}
.mainfunctionstyle {
  color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.sunfunctionstyle {
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 8px;
}
.taskstyle {
  color: red;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="key">left</button>
<table class="editableTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="cat">rose11</td>
    <td class="cat">red12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cat">rose21</td>
    <td class="cat">red22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cat1">rose31</td>
    <td class="cat">red32</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cat2">rose41</td>
    <td class="cat">red42</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Try that again, it seems my snippet was not saved

Answer (score 1):

I just made some modification in you code. Since `selected`, `selected1` and `selected2` have same css properties. I used only `selected` class. And i made a modification in js like this :

```
$(".selected1").removeClass('selected1')
$(this).addClass('selected1');
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".cat").dblclick(function() {
    var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
    $(this).addClass("cellEditing1")
    $(this).html("<input id='value' type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
  })


  $('tr').click(function() {
    $('.selected1').removeClass('selected1');
    $(this).addClass('selected1');

  });

  $(".cat").on("click", function() {
    $(".selected1").removeClass('selected1')
    $(this).addClass('selected1');
  });
  $(".cat1").on("click", function() {
    $('.selected1').removeClass('selected1')
    $(this).addClass('selected1');
  });

  $("#key").click(function() {

    var sl = parseInt($(".selected").css("padding-left"));
    sl = sl >= 20 ? "20" : "+=20";

    $(".selected").css({
      "padding-left": sl

    });
    var sq = parseInt($(".selected2").css("padding-left"));
    sq = sq >= 40 ? "40" : "+=20";

    $(".selected2").css({
      "padding-left": sq

    });
    $(".cat.selected").each(function() {
      var prevTd = $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').find('td:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')');
      console.log('Current td index: ' + $(this).index());
      console.log('Previous td content: ' + prevTd.text());

      prevTd.addClass("mainfunctionstyle");
      prevTd.find('input').addClass("mainfunctionstyle");



    });

    $(".cat1.selected2").each(function() {

      var paddingLeftpl = parseInt($(this).css("padding-left"));
      if (paddingLeftpl == 40) {
        $(".selected2").addClass("taskstyle");
        $(".selected2").find('input').addClass("taskstyle");
      }

    });
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.selected1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.selected2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.editableTable {
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.editableTable td {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 17px;
}

.editableTable .cellEditing1 input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.editableTable .cellEditing1 {
  padding: 0;
  height: 1px;
}

.mainfunctionstyle {
  color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.sunfunctionstyle {
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 8px;
}

.taskstyle {
  color: red;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="key">left</button>
<table class="editableTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="cat">rose11</td>
    <td class="cat">red12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cat">rose21</td>
    <td class="cat">red22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cat1">rose31</td>
    <td class="cat">red32</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cat2">rose41</td>
    <td class="cat">red42</td>
  </tr>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks your help. i have one more doubt how i select multiple TR using control button

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924670/select-multiple-rows-using-control-and-shift-key

Comment: here is one problem you change the selected1 selected 2 and selected it make my code another problem so with out changing this how i solve this

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="key">left</button>
<table class="editableTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="cat">rose11</td>
    <td class="cat">red12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cat">rose21</td>
    <td class="cat">red22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cat1">rose31</td>
    <td class="cat">red32</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cat2">rose41</td>
    <td class="cat">red42</td>
  </tr>
```

CSS:

```
.selected {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.selected1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.selected2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.editableTable {
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.editableTable td {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 17px;
}
.editableTable .cellEditing1 input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.editableTable .cellEditing1 {
  padding: 0;
  height: 1px;
}
.mainfunctionstyle {
  color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.sunfunctionstyle {
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 8px;
}
.taskstyle {
  color: red;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  $(".cat").dblclick(function() {
    var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
    $(this).addClass("cellEditing1")
    $(this).html("<input id='value' type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
  })


  $('tr').click(function() {
    $('tr').removeClass('selected1');
    $(this).addClass('selected1');

  });


  $(".cat1").on("click", function() {
    $(this).removeClass('selected2')
    $(this).addClass('selected2');
  });

  $("#key").click(function() {

    var sl = parseInt($(".selected").css("padding-left"));
    sl = sl >= 20 ? "20" : "+=20";

    $(".selected").css({
      "padding-left": sl

    });
    var sq = parseInt($(".selected2").css("padding-left"));
    sq = sq >= 40 ? "40" : "+=20";

    $(".selected2").css({
      "padding-left": sq

    });
    $(".cat.selected").each(function() {
      var prevTd = $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').find('td:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')');
      console.log('Current td index: ' + $(this).index());
      console.log('Previous td content: ' + prevTd.text());

      prevTd.addClass("mainfunctionstyle");
      prevTd.find('input').addClass("mainfunctionstyle");



    });

    $(".cat1.selected2").each(function() {

      var paddingLeftpl = parseInt($(this).css("padding-left"));
      if (paddingLeftpl == 40) {
        $(".selected2").addClass("taskstyle");
        $(".selected2").find('input').addClass("taskstyle");
      }

    });
  });
});
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nsyvc1hm/).

Comment: Why use a fiddle instead of Stack Snippet? And you need to explain what you changed and why. No one is going to read through all the code trying to figure out what the differences are.

Comment: @Barmar: I don't know how to use the Stack Snippet.

Comment: It's alot like jsfiddle.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0

Comment: Click on Copy Snippet to Answer, then edit it to make your changes.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it help you !
I used toggleclass of jquery : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.as

> The toggleClass() method toggles between adding and removing one or
>   more class names from the selected elements.
>
> This method checks each element for the specified class names. The
>   class names are added if missing, and removed if already set - This
>   creates a toggle effect.
>
> However, by using the "switch" parameter, you can specify to only
>   remove, or only add a class name.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
    } );
} );
```

```css
.highlighted {
    color: #261F1D;
    background-color: #E5C37E;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="1" border="1" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>2010/03/11</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/08/14</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2011/06/02</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>2009/10/22</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/05/07</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2008/10/26</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/03/09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/12/09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/12/16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010/02/12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>2009/02/14</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2008/12/11</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>2008/09/26</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2011/02/03</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>2011/05/03</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2009/08/19</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2013/08/11</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/07/07</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2012/04/09</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2010/01/04</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>2012/06/01</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2013/02/01</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/12/06</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2011/03/21</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2009/02/27</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2010/07/14</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/11/13</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: You need to explain what you changed and why, not just post a bunch of code.

Comment: I used toggleclass of jquery. The toggleClass() method toggles between adding and removing one or more class names from the selected elements. This method checks each element for the specified class names. The class names are added if missing, and removed if already set - This creates a toggle effect.