# Can someone explain why this javascript code alert these (item3 undefined, item3 undefined, item3 undefined)

Tags: javascript

```
function init(list) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i<list.length; i++) {
        var item = 'item' + list[i];
        result.push( function() { alert( item + ' ' +list[i] ) } );
    }
    return result;
}
function foo() {
    var list = init([1,2,3]);
    for (var j = 0; j<list.length; j++) {
        list[j]();
    }
}
foo();
```

**The script alerts:**

- item3 undefined
- item3 undefined
- item3 undefined

Comment: Closures and scope -> http://jsfiddle.net/YQ7vp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the good-old `i` + scope issue again ;)... the solution:

```
function init(list)
{
    var item, result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i<list.length; i++)
    {
        item = 'item' + list[i];
        result.push((function(val, idx)
        {//create this function with its own scope
            return function()
            {//return this function, which has access to val and idx
                alert(val+' '+list[idx]);
            };
        }(i, item));//pass vals of i and item to function, and call it here (IIFE)
    }
    return result;
}
```

Why? all functions created in a given scope, have access to any variable declared in that higher scope. So the functions you're pushing into `result` have, indeed access to `i`, `item` and `list`. They have *access*, but don't own their own *copy* of those variables.
on each iteration of the for loop, i is incremented, so it's 0, 1, 2,3. When its value hits 3, the it's value is no longer `< list.length` so the loop ends. But inside the functions you're creating `list[i]` evaluates to `list[3]`, which is undefined.

The same applies to `item`, the variable is declared in the `init` function, where it's reassigned on each iteration, too, hence whichever of the created functions you call, they will reference whatever was last assigned to `item`: *"item3"* in your case.

I've posted [a fairly lengthy answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16472719/1230836) that explains this in detail, *and* I've added a lot of info to the [tag-wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/iife/info), too. For now, you can easily test this like so:

```
function init(list)
{
    var j, result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i<list.length; i++)
    {
        var item = 'item' + list[i];
        result.push( function() { alert( item + ' ' +list[i] ) } );
        for (j=0;j<=i;j++)
        {
            result[j]();
        }
    }
    alert(i);
    return result;
}
```

This will alert something like:

```
//i = 0
item1 1
//i = 1
item2 1
item2 2
//i=2
item3 1
item3 2
item3 3
//outside loops, alert i:
3
```

Comment: Guys the code above is a question, I got the wrong answer that is why I am asking why it happen that way? My answer is item1 1, item2 2, item3 3.

Comment: @rolz: My answer starts off with code that works as expected, but after that, I explain _why_ your code alerts what it alerts, and I link to another answer with drawings and tons of extra info on how JS evaluates expressions

Comment: @rolz: The construction that is used to solve this is often referred to as an IIFE. I've recently added a lor of details on the matter in the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/iife/info), so if there's anything still unclear, you might want to check that out

Comment: why is it no alert happens in this function call init([1,2,3])?

Comment: @rolz: If you're using my first snippet: when I call `result.push`, I'm passing a function object, returned by an IIFE. It's this returned function that has `alert(...)` in it's body. This function isn't called yet, so the alert isn't called. If you use my second snippet (which doesn't solve the scope-issue), there will be alerts (the ones I listed @ bottom of my answer)

Answer (score 1):

By the time you call `list[j]();`, the value of `i` is `3` (as the `for (var i = 0; i<list.length; i++) {` will have reached the end.

Answer (score 0):

Because the internal function that you are storing in the array takes the reference to the variable not the value in each iteration. You can call a function with `i` as a parameters that return the function that you want to keep in the array, and because you are creating a new function and javascript functions create a new scope and take the value of the parameter, it take the position of memory that `i` points in that moment that you call the function;

```
function init(list) {
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i<list.length; i++) {
        var item = 'item' + list[i];
              result.push( (function (i){ return function() { alert( item + ' ' +list[i] )};})(i))
    }
    return result;
}
function foo() {
    var list = init([1,2,3]);
    for (var j = 0; j<list.length; j++) {
        list[j]();
    }
}
foo();
```

Comment: By the way what this list[j]() does?

Comment: You're not solving any of the problems: you suggest masking `i` using an argument, but then fail to pass it (`list[j]()` should be `list[j](j)`), but the `item` var is still not scoped correctly, and will be `item3` every time