# How to defined Global variable scop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to use a variable inside another function but is not defined!  I tried it with this and var. how can I make it defined in another function? in the code below, I want to add actionInt by 1 in "next" but it is not defined. any idea?

```
        func1 : function(event) {

            if (action == "test"){
                console.log(test clicked);
            }


            else if (action == "test2"){

                console.log(test2 clicked);
            }



        },
```

Comment: Where is `currentData`?

Comment: remove this because it's not needed to refer to local variable

Comment: @Ian Brindley, sorry I meant actionInt

Comment: If you want your value to be "global" you need to set that var outside of your onPageClick method. When your calling this.loadPage this will refer to the actual element that raised the event and probably not your class that has the loadPage method, maybe thats your error?

Comment: You do realize that, in both cases `console.log(this.actionInt++)` or `console.log(this.actionInt--);` will log the same value, right? I mean: the statements are saying: log the current value of `this.actionInt`, then increment/decrement it by one... in other words: if `this.actionInt` is 25, you'll always log 25, then reassign the property to hold _either_ 26 or 24

Answer (score 1):

that's because `actionInt` was declared in this line:

```
var actionInt = parseInt(action);
```

And you're incrementing `this.actionInt++`, where `this` is the call context, determined ad-hoc (probably the object to which you attached the event listener).
I strongly recommend you [read up on what `this` actually references](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in JS, just like I'd also suggest you specify [the radix when using `parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), and realize that this doesn't make sense:

```
actionInt = parseInt(action, 10);//action is number?
if (action === 'next')//action is string?
```

if `action` is `next` or `previous`, `parseInt` will always return `NaN`, which, when incremented, still is `NaN` (Not A Number + 1 is Not A Number)

But which ever way you look at it, I think you're actually looking for a closure:

```
onPageClick : (function(actionInt)
{
    return function(event)
    {
        var action = event.target.innerHTML;
        this.loadPage(actionInt, 25);//what is this?
        if (action == "Next"){
            console.log(actionInt++);//no this
        }
        else if (action == "previous"){
            console.log(actionInt--);
        }
    };
}(0)),//pass initial actionInt value here
```

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472577/javascript-how-to-make-this-code-work/#16472719) on details on how JS resolves expressions/variable names and how closures work...
If `actionInt` is a global variable, you can omit the IIFE, and just use `actionInt`, it'll resolve to the global variable by default (or throw an error if it wasn't defined in strict mode)

Answer (score 0):

In your case this refers to global scope(probably) - `window` object.

In such case as yours there's no need to use `this.variable = 0` just use `var variable = value;`

Comment: what is variable? where should I define it?