# Why when invoking a function is the first this the parent object, but on a subsequent function call this refers to the window object?

Tags: javascript

When initially invoking a function, the first `this` within the first function that is called refers to the parent object `foo` but on a subsequent function called by that first function `this` refers to the window object?

```
var foo = (function Obj(){
    var t = this;
    return  {
        getThis: getThis,
        getSecondThis: getSecondThis
    };
    function getThis(){ 
        console.log(this);
        console.log(t);
        getSecondThis()
        return false;
    }
    function getSecondThis(){ 
        console.log(this);
        console.log(t);
        return false;
    }
})();

foo.getThis();
```

If I change the call from `getSecondThis()` to `this.getSecondThis()` then the `this` within `getSecondThis()` refers to the parent object `foo` see the code below

```
var foo = (function Obj(){
    var t = this;
    return  {
        getThis: getThis,
        getSecondThis: getSecondThis
    };
    function getThis(){ 
        console.log(this);
        console.log(t);
        this.getSecondThis() //line edited
        return false;
    }
    function getSecondThis(){ 
        console.log(this);
        console.log(t);
        return false;
    }
})();

foo.getThis();
```

The `getSecondThis()` is  within the scope of the parent object `foo` but window is returned when `this` is not specified on the second call.

Comment: Put `"use strict";` before the `var` declaration in the outer anonymous function and see what happens.

Comment: Right. In "strict" mode, a function invoked with no context will see `this` set to `undefined`. In "sloppy" (default, for now) mode, in such cases `this` is the global (`window`) object.

Comment: See my answer here for a full description of how "this" works in javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the way JS binds the calling context: JS binds the context (the `this` reference) ad-hoc. Meaning: depending on how, where and by what means it is invoked, `this` will reference a different object.
I've explained this in some detail before [here, and in the linked answers found on the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174187/properties-of-javascript-function-objects)

Basically, functions are *first class objects*, meaning that, like any value, you can assign a function to a multitude of variables/properties. Of course, if you assign a function to an object (as a property), that function is often referred to as a method, and you'd expect `this` to point to the object that owns that method.
However, as Pointy noted in the comments: An object cannot *own* another object. Objects can be referenced by one or more properties of another object.

JS will kindly set `this` to refer to the object that owns the function. But if you then assign the object to a variable, it would make no sense to have `this` point to that same object. Think of situations where you're passing functions as function arguments (callbacks in jQuery and so on). You probably want `this` to reference the new context (certainly the case in jQ event handlers!).
If no context is provided, JS sadly defaults the `this` reference to the global object.

You can explicitly *bind* a function to a given context using the `Function.prototype.bind` call.
If you want to specify the context for a single call, you can use `Function.prototype.call(context, arg1, arg2);` or `Function.prototype.apply(context, [args]);`

Most larger projects (toolkits like jQ for example) solve this issue by taking advantage of closure scoping. Using the module pattern, for example, is a common, and easy way to control the context. [I've explained this, too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472577/javascript-how-to-make-this-code-work), complete with graphs to illustrate what is going on :)

Some examples/puzzles to make this easier to follow or more fun:

```
var obj = (function()
{//function scope
    'use strict';//this will be null, instead of global, omit this and this can be window
    var obj = {},
        funcOne = function()
        {
            console.log(this, obj, this === obj);
            funcTwo(this);
            obj.funcTwo();
            obj.funcTwo(this);
            obj.funcTwo(obj);
        },
        funcTwo = function(that)
        {
            console.log(this, obj, this === obj, this === that, that === obj);
        };
        obj.funcOne = funcOne;
        obj.funcTwo = funcTwo;
        return obj;//is assigned to the outer var
}());
obj.funcOne();
//output:
//- first logs itself twice, then true
//then calls made in funcOne:
funcTwo()
console.log(this, obj, this === obj, this === that, that === obj);
//- this: undefined (omit 'use strict' and it'll be window), obj,
//     this === obj => false, this === that => false, that === obj => true
obj.funcTwo();
console.log(this, obj, this === obj, this === that, that === obj);
//logs obj twice, because obj.funcTwo means the context === obj
//this === obj is true (of course)
//that is undefined, so this === that and that === obj are false
//lastly
obj.funcTwo(this);
obj.funcTwo(obj);
```

You should be able to work that out. You know the context in which `funcOne` is being executed, and you know what the effects are of invoking `funcTwo` as a method of `obj`

***Rule of thumb:***
I hesitated to write this, because it's far from accurate, but 8/10 cases. Assuming no code has been meddling with contexts through `bind`, `call`, and `apply`, you can work out the context using this trick:

```
someObject.someMethod();
    /\        ||
    |===this===|
//another object:
var obj2 = {
    borrowed: someObject.someMethod,
    myOwn: function()
    {
        this.borrowed();
    }
};
obj2.myOwn();//this === obj2 (as explained above),
   \\
    \==> this.borrowed === obj2.borrowed 
            \\
             \==> ~= someObject.someMethod.call(obj2);//function is executed in context of obj2
//simple vars
var alias = someObject.someMethod;//assign to var
alias();//no owner to be seen?
   ||
?<==|
//non-strict mode:
[window.]alias();
 /\ implied ||
 ||         ||
 |==<this>===|
//strict mode
alias.call(undefined);//context is undefined
```

Comment: @Aaron: I'm sorry, it's not really that difficult, but I'm, perhaps, not quite the best tutor. It took me some time to understand how JS's `this` binding worked, too, but all of a sudden, it hit me. The second link (with the images) really helped me to understand closures

Comment: @Aaron: Added a very concise, basic, and incomplete rule of thumb. It's not accurate 100% of the time, but it does apply to your situation, and it _does_ help to get an understanding of what is happening, IMHO

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem this is a great explanation, but the idea that an object "owns" a method is a little suspicious to me, as there really is no inherent relationship between a function and any object. If properties on two different object refer to a single function, which "owns" it? Maybe I'm being too pedantic :)

Comment: @Pointy: You're quite right. I'll edit to something along the lines of _"an object owns a property, that is assigned a reference to a function object"_. It might be more confusing to the OP, but it is more accurate