# Modifying an element of array $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a 3rd party javascript library which requires a nested array to be passed to a function. I'm using this function several times, and so storing the array in a variable and passing it to the functions.  However, part of the string of 1 element of the array needs to be the current id of the thing I'm passing; I've got something that works that looks a bit like:

```
myArray = [["foo bar id","some data"],["foo2 bar2 id","some other data"]]

func1(($m1 = myArray.slice(0), 
       $.each($m1, function(i){
              $m1[0] = myArray[i][0].replace("id","1");
       })))
```

Is it really necessary to make a copy of the array; is there a way of doing it via the `$(this)` object, or would that not work because that's only in the scope of the `.each` loop, and doesn't get passed back to `func1`?

**Update**

The original answer below doesn't seem to work - the values of the array the 2nd time I reference it are the values given in the first instance:

```
myArray = [["foo bar id","some data"],["foo2 bar2 id","some other data"]]
func1(

  myArray = myArray.map(function(value)
  {
    value[0] = value[0].replace(/\bid\b/gi, '1');
    console.log(value[0]); //returns "foo bar 1" as expected
    return value;
  });

)

func1(

  myArray = myArray.map(function(value)
  {
    value[0] = value[0].replace(/\bid\b/gi, '2');
    console.log(value[0]); //This returns "foo bar 1", not "foo bar 2"!
    return value;
  });

)
```

**Update (full proper code!)**

To put it all into context, the 3rd party library is [jsmol](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsmol/), which allows molecular graphics to be displayed.  jsmol includes some convenience functions for simple html elements, the one I'm using is [Jmol.jmolMenu()](http://wiki.jmol.org/index.php/Jmol_JavaScript_Object/Functions#jmolMenu) - the nested array I've actually got is

```
arr = [ ["select model=id; color blue", "colour this model blue"],
        ["select model=id; color green", "colour this model green"]
      ]
```

and then I have *n* molecular models displayed in the same `applet`, which jsmol references as 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, ... etc

I have *n* `Jmol.jmolMenu`s (which just create html select lists); the 1st one to change the colour of 1.1, the second one to change the colour of 2.1 and so on - this is where I need to change the value of the id to the relevant model, and why the replace can only replace the current instance of the current copy - otherwise it makes the lists for the other molecules not work!

In my first menu, I effectively need

```
Jmol.jmolMenu(jmol,
    [
      ["select model=1.1; color blue", "colour this model blue"],
      ["select model=1.1; color green", "colour this model green"]
    ]
);
```

and in my second:

```
Jmol.jmolMenu(jmol,
    [
      ["select model=2.1; color blue", "colour this model blue"],
      ["select model=2.1; color green", "colour this model green"]
     ]
);
```

I hope this makes a bit of sense, and explains why I need the arrays modifying when I do (which might have seemed weird before!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update:*
Seeing as you're dealing with a nested array, my initial answer doesn't quite suffice, but still, it's an easy fix:

```
var myArray = ["foo bar id","my first array"];
myArray = myArray.map(function(value)
{
    return value.replace('id','1');//replaces only the first occurrence of "id", thouh
});
```

Why are you using jQuery to alter a standard JS array? Why not use plain vanillaJS? It's faster, shorter and a lot easier to write here:

```
var myArray = [["foo bar id","some data"],["foo2 bar2 id","some other data"]];
myArray = myArray.map(function(value)
{
    value[0] = value[0].replace(/\bid\b/gi, '1');
    return value;
});
```

Just map, as before, but treat the `value` argument as the array that it is. If you need the keys of each sub-array, for example to access the corresponding id in another array:

```
var ids = ['1', '2'];
myArray = myArray.map(function(value, idx)//second argument is the key
{
    value[0] = value[0].replace(/\bid\b/gi, ids[idx]);
    return value;
});
```

That's all there is to it.

There is a *"gotcha"* you might encounter with your current code. As I mentioned in the comment, your `replace` call will only replace the first occurrence of *"id"* in the string, not all of them. It'll also replace "id", even if it is part of a word, and the replace call is case-sensitive:

```
'ID placid id'.replace('id', '1');//ID plac1 id
```

These issues can be solved by using a regex:

```
'ID placid id'.replace(/\bid\b/gi, '1');//1 placid 1
```

the `\b` in the pattern stands for a *word-boundary*. the `g` flag makes the pattern *global*, all occurrences of id will be replaced. the `i` flag makes the pattern case-insensitive.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I realised I could!

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than I implied - it's actually a nested array which is why I had a `$.each` to begin with; sorry that this wasn't clear

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect that I've got a nested array - I guess my next obvious question is whether the loop through the nested elements should be in the function or outside it - or does it not really matter?

Comment: @ChrisW: Updated my answer, added some more info, too. Note that I replaced the `.replace('id', '1')` with `replace(/\bid\b/gi, ids[idx])`. My answer explains what that's all about

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise I didn't need a loop!

Comment: @ChrisW: You're welcome... if this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted (sorry for nagging). Just a side-note: as an alternative to `Array.prototype.map`, you can use ECMAScript5's `Array.prototype.forEach` function, too (check MDN for the differences)

Comment: So, my actual question was meant to be why doesn't modifying `$(this)` work (which I originally tried before copying the array) - is this because of the scope of `.each`?

Comment: @ChrisW: no, `$(this)` doesn't work, because the callback passed to `$.each` is executed in the context of the element it iterates over (`myArray[0].apply(callback)`), which means that `$(this)` would be the same as writing `$(['foobar id', 'other value'])`, which makes no sense. If the context were a string, then `$('foobar')` would be interpreted as a DOM selector, which would make even less sense. What you could've done in `$.each` was: `this[0].replace`, because `this` would reference the sub-array` (or again, if it was a string: `this.replace`). But the latter wouldn't have worked

Comment: [check this answer out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16472719/1230836) for more details on context bindings of jQ callbacks and scope issues that they might cause

Comment: Hmm, sorry to come back to this - I've discovered a slight flaw! I'm sure it's something I've misunderstood but have updated my question

Comment: @ChrisW: `Array.prototype.map` actually applies the callback (the function you pass as argument) to _all_ values in the array, so applying it a second time makes no sense. Besides: all the occurrences of `id` have been replaced with 1, so the second `myArray.map` can't replace anything: `'foo bar 1'.replace(/id/, 2);` <-- there's no match for `/id/` that can be replaced! That's why I added the bit about using the index in the array to refer back to an array of ids, so you can replace the `id` substring with the corresponding id

Comment: Ah, I see... so do I really need to manually create a new array with the id values for every time I want to reference it? :/

Comment: @ChrisW: No, but using `Array.prototype.map`, you can create a copy, just have an id-array, and do something like: `var withIds = myArray.map(function(v, idx) { v[0] = v[0].replace(/\bid\b/gi, ids[idx]); return v;});`. With this, the `myArray` array will not be altered, but instead, you'll have a copy assigned to `withIds`, containing all of the data, but where `id` is replaced with the actual id

Comment: Hmm, so what's the advantage in me having to create a whole id array manually over my original code of using `.slice()` to create a copy for me that I then manipulated?

Comment: @ChrisW: I don't know. I don't know what it is you're actually trying to do, where you're doing it, and where the id's are coming from. I just assumed you had all id's at the ready, because your initial code was using `$.each`. If you don't then you don't need `Array.prototype.map`, or `$.each`, but you'd just manipulate those values you need to change. Besides: I'm not saying you should create an id array manually, it could well be fetched using an AJAX request

Comment: Argh! I'm really confused :/ you said `Array.prototype.map` creates a copy, but if it creates a copy, why are the values in the original referenced array changed? I don't understand what `.map` is doing. Is it looping through the nested arrays? I'm just a simple chemist trying to get some code working for someone! :(

Comment: @ChrisW: it's quite simple: the values in the original are changed because the values are arrays, Arrays are objects, and thus they are passed around by reference. `Array.prototype.map` does not change the array it maps, but rather returns a copy of that array. Sorry, I was a bit unclear about that. That's because your initial example array wasn't a 2D array, but an array of strings. `.map` does teh same as `$.each`: it iterates an array, and applies a function to each element in that array. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: PS: If you're trying to get some code working for someone else, there's nothing preventing you from saying _"Your mess, not mine"_ :-P. I'm off now, time to grab something to eat

Comment: Ha, it's my job to write code for them tho ;) I've updated my question with the actual context, it might help explain why I need to do what I'm doing :)